# Understanding <jsp:attribute> semantics

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I'm reading OCWCD by Charles Lyon on `<jsp:attribute>` and I couldn't understand this part. Would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Here it goes (excerpts from the book):

*Approach 1:*

```
<jsp:useBean>  
<jsp:attribute name="id">bean_name<jsp:attribute>
<jsp:useBean>
```

*Approach 2:*

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean_name"/>
```

> "The semantics of both approaches are the same, in that if an attribute is expecting the result of a request time expression, then the container will evaluate the contents of the `<jsp:attribute>` action; otherwise if the body content of `<jsp:attribute>` is a request time expression, a translation exception will be thrown."

Any idea what he's trying to say?

Comment: Looks very confusing to me, I haven't seen any `<jsp:attribute></jsp:attribute>` inside a `<jsp: useBean>` tag. As far as I know `<jsp:attribute>` are meant for setting values of attributes of `xml` tags not the properties of any `Bean`. For setting the properties the `<jsp: setProperty>` tags are used.

Answer (score 11):

JavaServer Pages 2.3 Specification statements

> • For standard or custom action attributes that **accept a request-time expression value**,
>   the Container must evaluate the body of the  action and use the result of this evaluation as the value of the attribute. The body of the attribute action can be any JSP content in this case. If the type of the attribute is not String, the standard type conversion rules are applied, as per Section JSP.1.14.2.1, “Conversions from String values”.

example:

`<jsp:element>`'s attributes that accept a request-time expression value, so the following example will evaluate the body of the  action.

```
<jsp:element name="xmlElement">
    <jsp:attribute name="xmlElementAttr">${param.test}</jsp:attribute>
</jsp:element>
<jsp:element name="xmlElement">
    <jsp:attribute name="xmlElementAttr"><%=request.getParameter("test")%></jsp:attribute>
</jsp:element>
```

> • For standard or custom action attributes that **do not accept a request-time expression value**, the Container must use the body of the  action as the value of the attribute. A translation error must result if the body of the  action contains anything but template text.

example:

The `property` attribute of `<jsp:getProperty>` does not accept a request-time expression value. So the following example will get **a translation error**.

```
<jsp:getProperty name="bean1">
    <jsp:attribute name="property">${param.test}</jsp:attribute>
</jsp:getProperty>
```